# Why is this difference between order and setorder(v) by data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to order a data.table. With setorder(v) I receive different result as with base::order. How could I receive the same result, order?

I already have tried to solve with 1 column, but I should order by more columns.

```
1: (test = data.table(V1 = c("TeilA1_a", "TeilA_a", "TeilC1_a", "TeilA_a"), 
                      V2 = c("4", "3", "2", "1")))
 2:   test[order(V1)]
 3:   sort(test[[1]])
 4:   c(order(test[[1]]))
 5:   order(test[[1]])
 6:   test[c(order(test[[1]]))]
 7:   test[order(test[[1]])]
 8:   (setorderv(test, c("V1"), c(1)))
 9:   test[order(V1)]
10:  test[order(V1, V2)]
```

Why are results of lines `c(4,5)` identical, but `c(6,7)` not? I expect the same output of line 8 as line 6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `?setorder` (data.table_1.12.2):

> Also note that data.table always reorders in "C-locale" (see Details). To sort by session locale, use x[base::order(.)].

Further in Details

> data.table always reorders in "C-locale". As a consequence, the ordering may be different to that obtained by base::order. In English locales, for example, sorting is case-sensitive in C-locale. Thus, sorting c("c", "a", "B") returns c("B", "a", "c") in data.table but c("a", "B", "c") in base::order. Note this makes no difference in most cases of data; both return identical results on ids where only upper-case or lower-case letters are present ("AB123" < "AC234" is true in both), or on country names and other proper nouns which are consistently capitalized. For example, neither "America" < "Brazil" nor "america" < "brazil" are affected since the first letter is consistently capitalized.

Thanks to Frank, it is noted when order optimization is on, `order` is substituted internally with `data.table:::forder` whereas `test[(order(V1))]; test[c(order(V1))]; test[base::order(V1)]` does not and is instead retrieved from scope outside of `[`.

Thanks also to MichaelChirico, `test[c(order(V1))]; test[(order(V1))]` will default to `data.table:::forder` from data.table_1.12.4 onwards. Please kindly check out the [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md) for updates.

Hence, `test[order(V1), verbose=TRUE]` sorts by C-locale (just like `test[data.table::chorder(V1)]`) giving

```
#data.table_1.12.2
order optimisation is on, i changed from 'order(...)' to 'forder(DT, ...)'.
   rn       V1 V2
1:  1 TeilA1_a  4
2:  2  TeilA_a  3
3:  4  TeilA_a  1
4:  3 TeilC1_a  2
```

while `test[base::order(V1)]; test[(order(V1)), verbose=TRUE]; test[c(order(V1)), verbose=TRUE]` gives

```
   rn       V1 V2
1:  2  TeilA_a  3
2:  4  TeilA_a  1
3:  1 TeilA1_a  4
4:  3 TeilC1_a  2
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
test = data.table(rn=1:4, V1 = c("TeilA1_a", "TeilA_a", "TeilC1_a", "TeilA_a"), V2 = c("4", "3", "2", "1"))
```

Comment: Maybe worth noting that the internal data.table:::forder is substituted inside DT[order()], while OP seems to mistakenly believe it's base::order being used. Their DT[c(order())] just yields base::order by circumventing data.table's parsing of the call (where it looks for order being the top-level function). They can use verbose=TRUE for details.

Comment: FWIW `DT[c(order())]` will also use `forder` in the development version of `data.table` (and from 1.12.4 onwards)